# Disable spell checking through magic comments

Tags: texstudio, comments, spelling, magic-comment

I use TeXstudio 2.11.2, and I want to know if there is a way to disable spell checking through magic comments. Something like this:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = disable
```

Comment: This is not supported.

Comment: @TimHoffmann, if you are sure, please, answer the question to let me accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling spellchecking through magic comments is currently not supported. The spellchecking magic comment is:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = [language]
```

If there is no dictonary for `language` (e.g. in your example "disable") the command is ignored and the global spelling setting of the editor is used (`Options -> Language Checking -> Spell Check -> Default Language`).